# increasing or decreasing the input value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple webshop cart and i'm currently stuck with a problem.
I want to increase or decrease the value of the input whenever i click on the plus or minus button.
To show the plus and minus button, please click "add to cart".
How do i increase or decrease the value of the input whenever i click on the plus or minus button?
Thank You in Advance.

```js
const foodList = document.getElementById('foodList');
const foodListOrder = document.getElementById('foodOrderList');
const inputAmount = document.getElementById('input');
const plusBtn = document.getElementById('plusBtn');
const minusBtn = document.getElementById('minusBtn');


foodList.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
        let parentButton = event.target.parentNode;  
        let button = parentButton.firstElementChild;
        let addListOrder = document.createElement('li');

        parentButton.removeChild(button);

        addListOrder.innerHTML = `${parentButton.textContent} <input type="text" id="input" value="1"> <button id="plusBtn">+</button> <button id="minusBtn">-</button>`
        foodListOrder.appendChild(addListOrder);
    }
})
```

```css
ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Food List</p>
        <ul id="foodList">
            <li>Chicken <button>Add to cart</button></li>
            <li>Meat <button>Add to cart</button></li>
            <li>Hot-Dog <button>Add to cart</button></li>
            <li>Fries <button>Add to cart</button></li>
            <li>Hamburger <button>Add to cart</button></li>
            <li>Ice-Cream <button>Add to cart</button></li>
            <li>Spaghetti <button>Add to cart</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div>
        <p>My Shopping Cart</p>
        <ul id="foodOrderList">
        </ul>
    </div>


    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well what can you do is instead of giving static and same id for each plus and minus button you can give them dynamic IDs in the basis of your item.
Something like

```
addListOrder.innerHTML = `${parentButton.textContent} <input type="text" id=${input + parentButton.textContent}value="1"> <button id=${add + parentButton.textContent}>+</button> <button id=${remove + parentButton.textContent}>-</button>`
```

In this way you will have unique id for every fields and you can add event listener or onClick function to the button or listen to the event fired from which input field using event listener.

Update the value with that ID recieved through event.